# Python selenium find text on page

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with finding text on page. I found solution for single occurrence like:

```
   if  "tutu"  in driver.page_source:
   else:
```

But now I'm looking for some solution to find 2 same text. ("tudu" and other "tudu")

Comment: `if "this thing" in text and "other thing" in text:`

Comment: But the problem is this thing and other thing is the same text

Comment: How are `tudu` and the other `tudu` connected/related?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `count()` string method.

```
if driver.page_source.count("some text") == 2:
```

Incase, two or more than two is okay:

```
if driver.page_source.count("some text") >= 2:
```